# Giving add or remove rows permission in protected excel file in macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to give permission to add or remove rows in the protected excel. The permission should be only to have of the page, that you can't add or remove rows in the whole worksheet, only specific rows should have this privilege. I write this code to give permission to merge or unmerge cells.

```
Sub Merge_unmerge_libraryprocedures()
    CCControls.UnProtect
    If Selection.Merg = True Then
        Selection.UnMerge
    Else:
      Selection.Merge
    End If
    CCControls.Protect
End Sub
```

Now I want to add to the code so that the user can also add or remove rows. If not how can I change the whole just to allow the user to edit part of the worksheet. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can do it in same way by un-protecting, Adding/Removing specific row and finally re-protecting the workbook.

Comment: can u suggest or help me with the coding?

Comment: A good start is just take your Macro Recorder and protect and unprotect your sheet... You should show some effort.

Comment: I do not know what is your specific criteria to check if the row to be added/removed  and which part it should be allowed. `Try If..End If` to specify your criteria in the above code and share the updated code if you still face issues.

Comment: there is no specific criteria to add or remove rows, all rows after A6 can be edited (DDED OR REMOVED)but any row before that is always protected